# Request is working with Postman but generated snippet does not

Tags: javascript, ajax, postman

So I am trying to send a GET Request in my JavaScript via AJAX. The problem is that I can send the Request in Postman and it works fine. When I use the feature to generate the AJAX code and I insert it in the my local index.html the Request seems to be blocked.

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://www.bibsonomy.org/api/posts?resourcetype=bookmark&group=ukp&format=json",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Basic key",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Console output:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
 at https://www.bibsonomy.org/api/posts?resourcetype=bookmark&group=ukp&format=json. 
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

I have no idea why it is not working and why Postman does not get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the header of the request.

Comment: I have added `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` no luck

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add this to your settings

```
xhrFields: {
   withCredentials: true
},
crossDomain: true
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to be handled from the server side. Only if the server adds a header that the it permits requests from `localhost:port`(if you are in development), 
 or you can add

set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` for accepting requests from all clients,
browser will be able to successfully complete the request.

The cross origin validation is a browser provided security against Cross domain attacks. The browser sends a preflight (OPTIONS) request to the server to ensure the request will be a valid one, and on successful return only a valid request will be sent.
So the reliable way to fix this, is a fix in the api provider(server) to accept requests from your domain/localhost.

However you can do a work around for just your browser, you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for such a method.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I can not influence the provider/server.